# How to log the sdk ver of VungleAdsSDK(7.1.0) in obj-c ,i used the VungleAdsSDKVersionNumber & VungleAdsSDKVersionString[] but not getting crrct ver

Tags: ios, vungle-ads

updated vunglesdk to vungleadssdk , but not able to log its sdk version in xcode obj-c

i tried using these 2 methods specified in the header file . but not correct version coming up
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double VungleAdsSDKVersionNumber;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char VungleAdsSDKVersionString[];